# How to interpret output of "autoplot" on a regression task in mlr3 (R)?

Tags: r, mlr3

Check section 2.2.2 of the mlr3 book: https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/tasks.html

Can someone please explain how to interpret the output charts of the line:

```
# pairs plot (requires package GGally)
autoplot(task, type = "pairs")
```

Specifically, what's the curve between 'mpg' and itself? I understand correlation across target variable and features. Also, what's the dot-plot?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about interpreting the results from statistical models, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there. At the very least include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or the output so we can see what you are seeing.

Comment: It's simply a density estimation of said feature. If you read the [help page](https://mlr3viz.mlr-org.com/reference/autoplot.TaskRegr.html) carefully you can see that `autoplot.TaskRegr` calls `GGally::ggpairs()`. On its [help page](https://ggobi.github.io/ggally/reference/ggpairs.html) you can find more details.

Comment: Thanks @jakob-r -- I thought the same but got confused with the markings on Y-axis for the 'mpg' variable. I guess this is a continuous graph of the fractions of 'mpg' that are at a given value? E.g. 2% of 'mpg' are at the value of 10?